# Does update get called before all functions are done processing? SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In SpriteKit

I have a basic rope with an attached ball swinging.(made with joints)
if I call a function that sets dynamic false to all segments and then enable them all again,(while swinging) the swinging motion gets messed up.

is it possible that the scene update function gets called BEFORE the function above is fully completed?

in this case. how would I make sure the function is completed before update is called.

Comment: google spritekit update cycle

Comment: i googled so much I decided to join stack overflow instead. I studied the apple API with the piechart etc. and I tried call this function in update, didSimulatePhysics and didFinnishUpdate. same result

Comment: google what i told you, and click the 1st link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819201/update-function-does-not-keep-up-with-moving-sprite

does not solve the problem

Comment: no idea what you did, google points to this https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjAg823sOjTAhULOSYKHX5VCG0QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Freference%2Fspritekit%2Fskscene&usg=AFQjCNHs30uBig08b0sLgBblKxPDvnfZnA

Comment: Yea well the API didn't help to answer my question. I believe that all calculations would be completed BEFORE next cycle begins. But this problem suggests otherwise. like the rendering cycle is asynchronous to user defined functions or something...

Comment: it tells you exactly what you need to know, your swinging function is happening on the main thread if you are using sprite kit physics, so there is no asynchronous calls happening

Comment: you know exactly how update works and what methods are called in the update cycle, find the method that gets called at the time you need your function to call, and place the function there

Comment: This might be a bad example tho because the physics bodies should lose their velocities when dynamic is set to false? that would explain the messed up motion

Comment: it shouldnt lose the velocity it should just ignore it,  but then again this is apple so anything is possible with them

Comment: "it tells you exactly what you need to know, your swinging function is happening on the main thread if you are using sprite kit physics, so there is no asynchronous calls happening"

So the answer to my question: "is it possible that the scene update function gets called BEFORE the function above is fully completed?"

is no :)

Comment: well. if I call the function from didFinnishUpdate it should not affect the swing motions from what I understand from the API...

Comment: put your code in didSimulatePhysics. update won't be called until next frame